# Cómo integrar stripe en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, stripe

Me gustaría conocer paso a paso cómo puedo integrar stripe en mi app en Android.
He desarrollado una tienda virtual y necesito implementar el proceso de pago con tarjeta y para ello he decidido usar Stripe, aunque la documentación y los ejemplos que he seguido parecen estar obsoletos o incompletos.
Sigo esta documentación https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/setup
Y me he descargado este ejemplo https://github.com/stripe-samples/sample-store-android, pero no consigo que funcione en android studio y por eso les pido ayuda.

El primer paso en el que me atasco del tutorial es donde dice...

> Once you’ve retrieved a token from Stripe on your server, you’re going to want to do something with the payment details you just collected.

Yo no tengo ningún servidor. Estoy desarrollando en Android mi app. Qué servidor debería tener? Cómo lo implemento? Alguna recomendación a este respecto?
Cómo recojo ese token? No puedo hacerlo desde mi app en Java?

Sigo adelante en el tutorial y en https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/standard
Entiendo que esos ephemeral keys se crean en el backend, aunque lamentablemente el ejemplo que aparece en https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend/blob/master/web.rb es en ios, cuando yo estoy trabajando en Android.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sigo esta documentación https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/setup Y me he descargado este ejemplo https://github.com/stripe-samples/sample-store-android, pero no consigo que funcione en android studio y por eso les pido ayuda.

Hemos modificado el sample de Android. Lo puedes descargar corriendo el siguiente comando con el [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli):

```
stripe samples create accept-a-card-payment
```

> Yo no tengo ningún servidor. Estoy desarrollando en Android mi app. Qué servidor debería tener? Cómo lo implemento? Alguna recomendación a este respecto? Cómo recojo ese token? No puedo hacerlo desde mi app en Java?

Por el momento efectivamente necesitas un servidor para generar el PaymentIntent. Más detalles [aquí](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#android-create-server-side).

> Sigo adelante en el tutorial y en https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/standard Entiendo que esos ephemeral keys se crean en el backend, aunque lamentablemente el ejemplo que aparece en https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend/blob/master/web.rb es en ios, cuando yo estoy trabajando en Android.

<strike>Aunque ese repositorio sólamente dice `ios`, también se puede utilizar para Android.</strike> Ahora renombramos el repositorio a `https://github.com/stripe/example-mobile-backend/`. Muchas gracias por el feedback!